# Alternative definition of physical states

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, vertex-algebras

Suppose that we have a vertex operator algebra $V$ with a conformal element $\omega$  and the associated conformal field
$$
Y(\omega,z) = \sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} L_kz^{-k-2}\,,
$$
where $L_k$ satisfy the Virasoro commutation relations for come conformal weight $c$ and $L_{-1}=T$ is the translation operator. We can define the subspaces $P_i\subset V$ by requiring for $v\in P_i$ to satisfy
$$
L_k v = iv\delta_{k,0} \,.
$$
The Lie algebra of physical/primary states is then defined by $P_1/TP_0$.

Alternatively, there is a way of defining the Lie bracket $[-,-]: V\times V/TV\to V$ lifting the usual construction of Borcherds as
$$
[u,\bar{v}] = [z^{-1}]\big\{Y(u,z)v\big\}\,,
$$
which is independent of the choice of lift $v$ of $\bar{v}$. Then
$$
\ker\Big\{[\omega, -]\Big\}
$$
defines a Lie sub-algebra, which can be shown to be identical to the one of physical states in the case of lattice vertex algebras.

All I am asking is if this alternative construction is familiar to anybody and if there is some more or less standard reference where it is already noted down.